# Search for "TODO" only in files which changed in specific mercurial changeset(s)?

Tags: mercurial

I'm working in a code base that already has a lot of "TODO" comments, and before I push my changeset(s) I want to make sure I haven't left any of my TODO comments in there (rather than actually doing it, or adding it to the new-feature database and removing the comment).

At the moment I'm just using "TODO: Wilka" in each of the comments, so it's easy to search for. But is there a way with Mercurial I can search for "TODO" only in the files that have changed in a collection of changesets? Ideally, it would only search the lines that have actually changed - but even just the files would be good.

Answer (score 1):

to search a specific set of revisions you could do:

```
hg grep -r 0:3 "\bTODO:"
```

Comment: IMHO, this will show ALL the TODO's in the project, not only the ones he introduced?

Comment: That is a fair point - this will list all instances of "TODO:" in the given revisions.  Removing the '--all' will only return the first hit for each file match

Comment: also I dont think the question asks for ones that he introduces ("I can search for "TODO" only in the files that have changed in a collection of changesets?")

Comment: It also gives output detailing which revision the particular line was changed in.  I stand by my answer :) but edited my answer to remove the '--all' as I dont think its needed.

Answer (score 0):

Diff between wanted revisions piped to the grep, only modified files file be searched with the grep

```
hg diff -r 100:105 | grep TODO
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments, this is presumes that grep is installed (so non Windows enviroment)
@thanks Tim, if using Windoes, use findstr instead of the grep

Comment: This assumes grep is available - which is not case on (e.g) a standard windows box.

Comment: On Windows you can replace `grep` with `findstr`.  In this simple case, it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

The automated way is via Mercurial [commit hooks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook). The [examples](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples) may be helpful as might the [checkfiles](https://bitbucket.org/marcusl/ml-hgext/src/tip/checkfiles.py) extension [referred to by mercurial developers](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Check_for_tabs_or_trailing_whitespace_before_commit).

In my experience, commit hooks are a mixed bag and often do what you want but are irksome when you really want to commit a TODO. The [Shelve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension) attempts to work around this, but the cure can be worse than the problem.

I haven't explored the possibility of something like `hg com --but-ignore-my-TODO-hook` which could be nifty.

Comment: Don't you mean pre push hook?